# Azure policy create a deployifnotexists policy

Tags: azure, azure-policy

I am trying to create a `DeployIfNotExists` policy from an existing `AuditIfNotExists` policy. It doesn't error while deploying, but it errors saying "No related resources match the effect details in the policy definition." when the policy is evaluated. The `AuditIfnotExists` policy does work well when I deploy it to the same management group. I wonder if I have missed something.

This policy is to create an alert for deletion of NSG groups if one doesn't exist.
Here is the `DeployIfNotExists` policy - do you guys see any issue with it? Any input appreciated. Thank you.

```json
{
  "$schema":"https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion":"1.0.0.0",
  "parameters":{
    "effect":{
      "type":"string",
      "metadata":{
        "displayName":"Effect",
        "description":"Enable or disable the execution of the policy"
      },
      "allowedValues":[
        "AuditIfNotExists",
        "deployIfNotExists",
        "Disabled"
      ],
      "defaultValue":"deployIfNotExists"
    }
  },
  "variables":{
    "actionGroupName":"dsactiongroup"
  },
  "resources":[
    {
      "name":"CIS5.2.3-EnsureAuditDeleteNSG",
      "type":"Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions",
      "apiVersion":"2019-09-01",
      "properties":{
        "policyType":"Custom",
        "displayName":"CIS 5.2.3 Ensure that Activity Log Alert exists for Delete Network Security Group (Scored)",
        "description":"Monitor Activity Alerts exist for specific activities.",
        "mode":"all",
        "metadata":{
          "category":"Audit"
        },
        "parameters":{
          
        },
        "policyRule":{
          "if":{
            "allOf":[
              {
                "field":"type",
                "equals":"Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions"
              }
            ]
          },
          "then":{
            "effect":"[parameters('effect')]",
            "details":{
              "type":"Microsoft.Insights/ActivityLogAlerts",
              "existenceCondition":{
                "allOf":[
                  {
                    "allOf":[
                      {
                        "not":{
                          "field":"Microsoft.Insights/ActivityLogAlerts/condition.allOf[*].field",
                          "notEquals":"category"
                        }
                      },
                      {
                        "not":{
                          "field":"Microsoft.Insights/ActivityLogAlerts/condition.allOf[*].equals",
                          "notEquals":"Administrative"
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "allOf":[
                      {
                        "not":{
                          "field":"Microsoft.Insights/ActivityLogAlerts/condition.allOf[*].field",
                          "notEquals":"resourceType"
                        }
                      },
                      {
                        "not":{
                          "field":"Microsoft.Insights/ActivityLogAlerts/condition.allOf[*].equals",
                          "notEquals":"microsoft.network/networksecuritygroups"
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "allOf":[
                      {
                        "not":{
                          "field":"Microsoft.Insights/ActivityLogAlerts/condition.allOf[*].field",
                          "notEquals":"operationName"
                        }
                      },
                      {
                        "not":{
                          "field":"Microsoft.Insights/ActivityLogAlerts/condition.allOf[*].equals",
                          "notEquals":"Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/delete"
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              },
              "roleDefinitionIds":[
                "/providers/microsoft.authorization/roleDefinitions/749f88d5-cbae-40b8-bcfc-e573ddc772fa"
              ],
              "deployment":{
                "properties":{
                  "mode":"incremental",
                  "template":{
                    "$schema":"https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
                    "contentVersion":"1.0.0.0",
                    "parameters":{
                      
                    },
                    "variables":{
                      "actionGroupName":"dactiongroup"
                    },
                    "resources":[
                      {
                        "name":"NSGRuleDeleted",
                        "type":"Microsoft.Insights/activityLogAlerts",
                        "location":"global",
                        "apiVersion":"2017-04-01",
                        "properties":{
                          "description":"NSG Rule Deleted",
                          "enabled":true,
                          "condition":{
                            "allOf":[
                              {
                                "field":"category",
                                "equals":"Administrative"
                              },
                              {
                                "field":"operationName",
                                "equals":"Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/delete"
                              }
                            ]
                          },
                          "actions":{
                            "actionGroups":[
                              {
                                "actionGroupId":"[resourceId('Microsoft.Insights/actionGroups', variables('actionGroupName'))]"
                              }
                            ]
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    ],
                    "outputs":{
                      
                    }
                  },
                  "parameters":{
                    
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Still stuck with this guys -  trying to bump this up hoping someone with give some tips :)

Comment: did you find a solution? where do you see this error?

Comment: The error who got, has this explanation: A resource of the type defined in then.details.type and related to the resource defined in the if portion of the policy rule doesn't exist. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/how-to/determine-non-compliance

Comment: any hint on how to solve ?

Comment: Did you manage to fix it? Otherwise, provide a screenshot of your non-compliant error (Compliance details) - from "reason for non-compliance" and downwards.
If you fixed it, please upload solution for others to benefit from. Thanks

Comment: The type value is wrong, it should be a resource provider+resource type, e.g. `Microsoft.Insights/ActivityLogAlerts`. Error here: `"resources": [
  {
   "name": "CIS5.2.3-EnsureAuditDeleteNSG",
   "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions",`

Answer (score 1):

- To check the cause of policy compliance, you should navigate to Azure Policy > Compliance > Resource Compliance tab >  Check the Compliance Reason Details.
- In my case, a policy did not had correct `existenceCondition`. Hence the evaluation expression kept failing. Providing correct evaluation condition fixed the issue for me.
- Note: Check the resource/subresource type the policy remediation task deploys under `effect`. The condition will be evaluated on that resource.

[image]

Comment: Here are some tools that can help: [Azure Resource Explorer](https://resources.azure.com/subscriptions/) , [Resource Explorer](https://portal.azure.com/#view/HubsExtension/ArmExplorerBlade). You can also check the Deployment section in resource group to see Policy initiated deployment logs.